# switching between index of for loop from GUI in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to create a GUI with two push buttons. One represents the Next and another is back. These two buttons should switch the index of for loop. For example, when I press the next button it should go to next iteration (i+1) and by pressing back, it goes to (i-1).. I really appreciate for any answer.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend for-loop but a while loop.since you don't really want to run the code for e.g. 1000 steps but you want to do it while i is between 2 values. So u would have a catch line inside your loop which returns +1 for next and -1 for previous button. But be careful not to program unending loops and think about break/stop points.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change the loops index from a GUI.
The better approach would be to use a while loop, wait for one of the pushbuttons and get the new index from the figure:

```
hFig = figure(..) % create your figure somewhere here
setappdata(hFig, 'loopIndex', 0); % assuming you start at 0
while 1:
    uiwait(hFig); % this will wait for anyone to call uiresume(hFig)
    loopIndex = getappdata(hFig, 'loopIndex');
    % do whatever you're doing with the index
    % ...
    % ...
    % stop loop at some point:
    if <end-condition>: % pseudo-code, obviously
        break
```

And a pushbutton callback like:

```
function button_callback(hObject, evt, handles):
    hFig = ancestor(hObject, 'figure');
    % increment the loop index:
    setappdata(hFig, 'loopIndex', 1+getappdata(hFig, 'loopIndex'))
    % proceed with the loop code
    uiresume(hFig);
```